# MVCReportViewer error loading subreport

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services

I have a MVC4 application using MVCReportViewer to load a reporting, however the subreport is not loading and it returns this error:

```
Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'Actions', 
located at: C:\Projects\Report\ReportActions.rdlc. 
Please check the log files for more information.
```

Here is my view code:

```
@using Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms;
@using MvcReportViewer;
@using MvcReportViewer
@model ViewReport

@Html.MvcReportViewerFluent(Model.ReportPathTordlc).ProcessingMode(ProcessingMode.Local).LocalDataSource(Model.ReportDataSet, Model.Report).LocalDataSource(Model.ActionDataSet, Model.Actions).Attributes(new { Height = 900, Width = 800, style = "border: 2px solid #ddd" }).Method(FormMethod.Post);
```

The path to both .rdlc files are correct as I check it on the controller before load the view.

The reportPathTordlc displays right, 
I have a parameter to check against, so in my report.rdlc I inserted subreport with parameter. On the subreport I created a parameter. but still the subreport not showing.

On log files from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles` doesn't show any error, it only display this: `i INFO: Call to CleanBatch()`.

Search everywhere and didn't get luck yet.

Project from [here](https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research, I finally found a solution:

Its not the most elegant way, but works fine.

So to get done:

In controller:

```
// Init new DataTable
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
// Assign the data for Subreport
dt = dataToLoadInSubReport();
// Place it in Session
Session["dataToLoadInSubReport"] = dt;
```

In View:

```
// Remove the subreport .LocalDataSource, keep the Parent Report
@Html.MvcReportViewerFluent("~/Report/report.rdlc").ProcessingMode(ProcessingMode.Local).LocalDataSource("ReportDataSet", ReportDataTable).Method(FormMethod.Post);
```

In MvcReportViewer:

```
// Html head (Added the script below)
<script runat="server">
    void SubSubreportProcessing(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check if Session is not null
        if (Session["dataToLoadInSubReport"] != null)
        {
            // Get data in Session  
            System.Data.DataTable dt = Session["dataToLoadInSubReport"] as System.Data.DataTable;
            // Convert to dataview to filter
            System.Data.DataView dv = new System.Data.DataView(dt);
            if (dv != null)
            {
                // Get Subreport parameter
                var param1 = Convert.ToInt32(e.Parameters[0].Values[0]);
                // Filter DataView
                dv.RowFilter = "ID = " + param1;
                // Add Filtered DataView to DataSource specified in the Subreport rdlc file
                e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("DTSubReport", dv));
            }              
        }
    }

    protected void ReportViewer_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportViewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(SubSubreportProcessing);
    }
</script>
//Html body (add new attribute OnPreRender="")
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" ClientIDMode="Predictable" runat="server" OnPreRender="ReportViewer_PreRender"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

The parent should work as describe in the MVCReportViewer, this is to make the subreporting work together.

Hope this help someone out there.

Cheers